# Python Click library removes duplicated symbol passed as argument

Tags: python, symbols, python-click

When I pass a duplicated symbol to [click library](https://github.com/pallets/click) python, it removes one of the duplicated symbol.

How can solve this problem? is it a bug? there isn't a similar open and closed issues on documentation.

Example:

```
import click
    
@click.group()
def principal_cmd():
    """CLI group"""


@principal_cmd.command("print")
@click.argument("word", type=click.STRING)
def print_str(word: str):
    print(word)
```

in a prompt command:

```
principal_cmd print_str trial$$$1
```

I receive:

```
trial$$1
```

How is it possible to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: What operating system and command prompt shell are you using?  Are you sure that the literal string `trial$$$1` is getting passed to Python?  Or is the shell / cmd prompt doing some preprocessing?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and I tried with PowerShell and with GitBash. I don't know if shell / cmd are doing some preprocessing, how can I investigate it? Thanks